# Failed to read key key1 from store even tho key is 100% correct

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to create a release build for my app, but no matter what I do, it does not work. I get this error everytime:

> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key1 from store "C:\Users\CENSORED\Desktop\Ordner\Privates\Android Studio Key\keystore.jks": keystore password was incorrect
```

I created so many keys and passwords and this time (every time created it new), but it always says "keystore password was incorrect" even tho it is 100% correct!!

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('C:\\Users\\EXAMPLE\\Desktop\\Ordner\\Privates\\Android Studio Key\\keystore.jks')
        storePassword KEYPW
        keyAlias 'key1'
        keyPassword KEYPW
    }
}
```

### gradle properties

```
KEYPW='CENSORED'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, and I hate Android studio so much for that. Instead of writing this:

```
KEYPW='CENSORED'
```

you have to write this

```
KEYPW=CENSORED
```

Duh. Wasted another hour of my life